# How to iterate over whole array when I need i, j, k?

Tags: julia

Given `A` is a multi-dimensional array, can I collapse iteration through every element into one `for` statement if I need `i,j,k,etc.`? In other words, I am looking for a more compact version of the following:

```
for k in 1:size(A,3)
  for j in 1:size(A,2)
    for i in 1:size(A,1)
      # Do something with A[i+1,j,k], A[i,j+1,k], A[i,j,k+1], etc.
    end
  end
end
```

I think the solution is with `axes` or `CartesianIndices`, but I can't get the syntax right. Failed attempts:

```
julia> for (i,j,k) in axes(A)
         println(i)
       end
1
1
1

julia> for (i,j,k) in CartesianIndices(A)
           println(i)
       end
ERROR: iteration is deliberately unsupported for CartesianIndex. Use `I` rather than `I...`, or use `Tuple(I)...`
```

It would be great if in addition to a solution which defines `i,j,k`, you could also provide a solution that works regardless of the number of dimensions in `A`.

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there.  Read the message carefully:

> ERROR: iteration is deliberately unsupported for **CartesianIndex**.

It is the "pattern matching" in `(i,j,k) in CartesianIndices(...)` that fails, not the approach in general (I made the same mistake when reproducing the problem!).  You have to convert the individual `CartesianIndex`es to tuples first:

```
julia> for ix in CartesianIndices(A)
           println(Tuple(ix))
       end
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 1)
(3, 2, 1)
...
```

Comment: For others: The line `(i, j, k) = Tuple(ix)` will define `i`, `j`, and `k` in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

or using `axes`:

```
for (i,j,k) in Iterators.product(axes(x)...)
    println([i,j,k]) # or whatever else you want
end
```